# What is a difference between RSA-OAEP and RSAES-OAEP?

Tags: openssl, rsa, pkcs#1

very simple question.
What is a difference between RSA-OAEP and RSAES-OAEP?
Is it same???
And Can I decrypt using RSA-OAEP function from encryted data using RSAES-OAEP Algorithm

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

They both are the same. In RSAES, ES stands for `'Encryption System'`.